# date and time conversion in java while reading a file

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, file-io

I am having problem with date and time conversion in java.

Actually i am reading a string from a file splinting that string and storing it to a 
string array, now initializing some variables with this array. my problem is
I am saving this values to another file,while saving, the date format is changing i am posting my code.

**string i am reading from file:**

```
Wed May 02 12:07:54 EST 2012,Task 1 for  Test 1,20
```

**code i had writen:**

```
String s = br.readLine();
String[] list = s.split(",");
this.description = list[0];                
this.weight = Integer.parseInt(list[1]);
this.dueDate = new Date(list[2]);
//this.dueDate = dateFormat.parse(list[2]);
//SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E,dd MMM yyyy HH:mm.ss");
pw.println(description + "," + weight + "," + dueDate);
```

**output of my code:**

```
Thu May 03 03:07:54 EST 2012,Task 1 for  Test 1,20
```

Comment: You either haven't shown your exact code or your exact input - you should have got a NumberFormatException for "Task 1 for Test 1"  at the parseInt statement.

Comment: Yes and he tried to create the date from "20".

Comment: is this a problem with reading file or splitting string or date format ???

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `SimpleDateFormat` to **parse** the input date.

Assuming that your input data is formatted as you've posted, (so the date is list[0]) put this in instead:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
this.dueDate = dateFormat.parse(list[0]);
```

The important thing being that you're telling it to check for the time zone (`zzz`).
That should figure out the correct, actual, time that is described.

If you then just print out, it will (by default) print in your local timezone.

Comment: You tried it? I don't work for me, Wed and May can't be parse in input.

Comment: Yes, tried, did work for me.  I'm using openjdk - "OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (6b22-1.10.6-0ubuntu1)".
Never mind - well done for finding your own solution - that's what it's all about.

Comment: It probably only works with OpenJDK, I've only Oracle JDK and even with 1.6 it throws `java.text.ParseException`.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @GrefHNZ answer because it doesn't work with `list[0] = Wed May 02 12:07:54 EST 2012`. Wed and May can't be parse in input.

I made this solution (works only for JDK7):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    String s = "Wed May 02 12:07:54 EST 2012,Task 1 for Test 1,20";
    String[] list = s.split(",");
    String dateDesc = list[0];  
    String dateToParse = createStringToParse(dateDesc); //return "3 05 02 12:07:54 CEST 2012"
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("u MM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date dueDate=null;
    try {
        dueDate = dateFormat.parse(dateToParse);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(dueDate); //print "Wed May 02 12:07:54 CEST 2012"
 }
 private static String createStringToParse(String dateDesc) {
    int idx=dateDesc.indexOf(" ");
    String day = dateDesc.substring(0,idx);
    String month = dateDesc.substring(idx+1,dateDesc.indexOf(" ",idx+1));
    String rest = dateDesc.substring(dateDesc.indexOf(month)+month.length());
    switch(day){
        case "Mon" :
            day="1";break;
        case "Tue" :
            day="2";break;
        case "Wed" :
            day="3";break;
        case "Thu" :
            day="4";break;
        case "Fri" :
            day="5";break;
        case "Sat" :
            day="6";break;
        case "Sun" :
            day="7";break;
    }

    switch(month){
        case "Jan" :
            month="01";break;
        case "Feb" :
            month="02";break;
        case "Mar" :
            month="03";break;
        case "Apr" :
            month="04";break;
        case "May" :
            month="05";break;
        case "Jun" :
            month="06";break;
        case "Jul" :
            month="07";break;
        case "Aug" :
            month="08";break;
        case "Sep" :
            month="09";break;
        case "Oct" :
            month="10";break;
        case "Nov" :
            month="11";break;
        case "Dec" :
            month="12";break;
    }

    return day+" "+month+rest.replace("EST", "CEST");
}
```

To understand the `SimpleDateFormat` read the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.toString()` method and convert your `this.weight` to `String` without parsing.